# Substract border width from my horizontal list menu

Tags: css, list

here is my css code for a horizontal menu, it's cross browser and it works great, well it has 1 glitch. :)

The #menu which wraps everything has to have width of 100%, but when I put a border on it, the border adds to the width making it larger and screws up my layout. 
What I do is use jquery to substract the 2 pixel border. Is there a way to do this with css?

here is the menu's css:

```
#menu {
width: 100%;
margin: 0 0 1em 0;
padding: 0.5em 0 0 0;
border-right: solid 1px #555;
border-left: solid 1px #555;
border-bottom: solid 1px #555;
}
#menu ul {
margin: 0 0 0 0.5em;
padding: 0;
list-style-type: none;
}
#menu li {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
float: left;
width: 20%;
line-height: 1.5em;
margin-right: 1em;
margin-bottom: 0.5em;
background: url(images/headline.jpg) top repeat-x;
border: solid 1px #555;
text-align: center;
}
#menu a {
display: block;
width: 100%;
font-size: 70%;
text-decoration: none;
}
#menu a:hover {
background: #000 none;
}
```

Some notes: 
The menu has to be wrapped by a div that is used for styling background color, left margin/padding, etc. I've found no way to style the UL itself, because I can't clear the float inside it. Thus the height of the OL always equals zero.

Ty very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `outline` instead of `border`. It creates "borders" in the same way, only it places them on the inside of the frame, rather than the outside as `border` does.

Comment: thats a great ideea, tho outline does not work for ie7 or 6:(

Comment: also, after playing around with it, i don't think it works exactly as i thought it did...going to try a couple more things

Comment: its very hard to find a ul list which is cross browser compliant, without to many hacks, and this code seems to be ok except for the border problem

Comment: I think I'll delete the 100% width, its for ie5, I'm pretty sure not many people use it

Answer (score 0):

If you can ignore IE7 and below, you can use [box-sizing](http://jhop.me/css/css3/the-css3-box-sizing-concept-a-solution-to-a-longstanding-problem).